# xlUp - selected value 1 - and xlDown - selected value 4121 - vba fordrop downlist instead of -12

Tags: excel, vba

I am new on stackoverflow, finally a member after being a curious time to time visitor. So far I always found answers here, but it seems that I have to ask my own first question today :

I am trying to create a drop downlist in excel vba in a 1st sheet based on the list I created through a query in the next tab. The dropdown list is activated at the opening of the workbook.
I need the range for the dropdownlist in sheet 1 to be defined by selecting only the non empty cells in the column A.
I can not limit strictly my range as when the query is updated the list in sheet 2 can extend or shrink.

I created a short code that, strangely works once and then breaks: 
 - with xldown : select all cells to 4121 (12 from my list and rest blank)
 - with xlup : select only the first cell

Help would be very appreciated,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'DROPDOWN PROGRAM LIST

Worksheets("BANF code manager").Unprotect

Dim source_Prgm As Range
Dim Prgm_user As Range
Dim a As Integer

a = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row

Set source_Prgm = Worksheets("lists").Range("A1:A" & a)
Set Prgm_user = Worksheets("BANF code manager").Range("E8")

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="source_Prgm", RefersTo:=source_Prgm
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Prgm_user", RefersTo:=Prgm_user

With Prgm_user.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
     AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
         xlBetween, Formula1:="=source_Prgm"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
 End With
```

Comment: Please post your code in tags, not a picture of your code.

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour] and then [edit] your question to tell us what you want to do, what you have tried including a [mcve], and what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding a filter on the empty cells generated by xldown function. I found a practical solution but I still don´t understand the reason the of this error from xlDown. This also implies a lot of calculations. If someone has an idea how to optimize this it would be highly appreciated

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'DROPDOWN PROGRAM LIST

Worksheets("BANF code manager").Unprotect

Dim source_Prgm As Range
Dim Prgm_user As Range

Dim a As Long

 a = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row
 j = 1

 For i = 1 To a
      If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
      j = j + 0
      Else: j = j + 1
      End If

 Next

Set source_Prgm = Worksheets("lists").Range("A1:A" & j)
Set Prgm_user = Worksheets("BANF code manager").Range("E8")

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="source_Prgm", RefersTo:=source_Prgm
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Prgm_user", RefersTo:=Prgm_user
...
```